# Ошибка разбиения на модули

Tags: c++, vector, модули

Пытался разбить программу на модули, решил начать с модуля глобальных переменных.
Я в него вынес что всё мог, но необходимо еще вынести туда 2 вектора т.к. из основного файла программы отдельный функции не смогли получить доступ к этим векторам.
При вынесении пишет:
globals.h:36:1: error: 'vector' does not name a type
Хотя библиотека vector подключена
Я пытался вынести и в globals.h файл и в globals.cpp, никак не хочет работать.

Содержимое globals.cpp

```
#include <vector>
#include "graphics.h"
#include "globals.h"
int currentcolor;
int WSXmin;
int WSYmin;
int WSXmax;
int WSYmax;
int X,Y;
int CMD=0;
int currentstyle=0;
```

Содержимое globals.h

```
#include <vector>
#include "graphics.h"
#ifndef GLOBALS_H
#define GLOBALS_H
struct R
{
   int x1, y1;
};
struct LAYER
{
   int typeprim; 
   int x0, y0;
   int x1,y1;
   int x2,y2;
   int color;
   int style;
   int r1,r2;
};

struct BUTTON
{
   int x1,y1;
   int x2,y2; // координаты кнопки
   IMAGE *pic; // изображение 
};
extern int currentcolor;
extern int WSXmin;
extern int WSYmin;
extern int WSXmax;
extern int WSYmax;
extern int X,Y;
extern int CMD;
extern int currentstyle;
BUTTON bt[20];
vector<LAYER>Vlayers;
vector<R>Vredact;
#endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да просто не указано пространство имен, похоже...

Используйте не `vector`, а `std::vector`.

Comment: Всё работает, точно, спасибо!